# FragmentTabHost закрыть одну вкладку

Tags: android

Всем привет! не могу найти метод закрывающий одну определенную вкладку. тут есть http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html `clearAllTabs()` но он закрывает сразу все вкладки. в интернетах ничего по этому поводу не нашел. какие есть идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().removeView(
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(tabIndexToClose)
);
```

Comment: спасибо, плюсик пока поставить не могу)